# Proper way to do services with SPFX functional components

Tags: spfx, react

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do services in a React SPFx application. I'm still new to react and every example I have seen returns some html and what I need is a file that handles complex logic and return objects that I can reuse in other SPFx solutions. For example this is what I'm doing now.

```
import { BaseWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import {spfi, SPFI, SPFx} from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/fields";
import "@pnp/sp/files";
import "@pnp/sp/folders";
import "@pnp/sp/batching";
import "@pnp/sp/views";
import {
    IPropertyPaneDropdownOption,
  } from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane'; 
import {IColumnObject} from "./IColumnObject"; 
import {IDataObjectParams} from "./IDataObjectParams"; 
import { ISelectedObject } from "./ISelectedObject";

let spContext:SPFI;
export function setSPContext(context:BaseWebPartContext){
    spContext = spfi().using(SPFx(context));
}

export function otherThingThatNeedsToBeCalled(){
    ....something here
}
```

As you can see I have a let variable out in the open and I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it. Most of the examples have a class for their services but that seems to defeat the purpose of using functional components. I would like it if I could just call the function like I'm doing here and return objects as I need them. Any examples of how you are doing services with functional components would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I usually setup PnP context as below.
In below code I am setting up SP and Graph both. Also `siteUrl` parameter is used here. Pass the `siteUrl` to get data from that particular site collection. if it is not passed or blank, it will connect to the same site collection where WebPart is added.

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { objectDefinedNotNull, stringIsNullOrEmpty } from '@pnp/core/util';
import { graphfi, GraphFI, SPFx as graphSPFx } from '@pnp/graph';
import { LogLevel, PnPLogging } from '@pnp/logging';
import { spfi, SPFI, SPFx as spSPFX } from '@pnp/sp';
import '@pnp/sp/items';
import '@pnp/sp/lists';
import '@pnp/sp/webs';
import '@pnp/sp/profiles';
import '@pnp/sp/fields';
import '@pnp/sp/batching';
import "@pnp/graph/users";

export const getSP = (context: WebPartContext, siteUrl?: string): SPFI => {
    let _sp: SPFI = null;
    if (_sp === null && context !== null && objectDefinedNotNull(context.pageContext)) {
        _sp = (stringIsNullOrEmpty(siteUrl))
            ? spfi().using(spSPFX({ pageContext: context.pageContext })).using(PnPLogging(LogLevel.Warning))
            : spfi(siteUrl).using(spSPFX({ pageContext: context.pageContext })).using(PnPLogging(LogLevel.Warning))
    }
    return _sp;
}

export const getGraph = (context: WebPartContext, siteUrl?: string): GraphFI => {
    let _graph: GraphFI = null;
    if (_graph === null && context !== null && objectDefinedNotNull(context.pageContext)) {
        _graph = (stringIsNullOrEmpty(siteUrl))
            ? graphfi().using(graphSPFx(context)).using(PnPLogging(LogLevel.Warning))
            : graphfi(siteUrl).using(graphSPFx(context)).using(PnPLogging(LogLevel.Warning))
    }
    return _graph;
}
```